# Send environment variable as a command line argument inside a remote ssh of the jenkins

Tags: ruby, git, shell, jenkins, webhooks

I want to pass the post content parameter of the generic webhook trigger as a command line argument to the ruby script on remote ssh. Could someone please help me in achieving the same.

Here is what I am doing:
In Jenkins, under Generic WebHook Trigger, I am using $.ref(which is the branch name of the git).

Under Build-> Execute shell script on remote host using ssh, I am trying to run the ruby script. And I want to pass the above env variable "ref" as a command line argument to the ruby script:
For example: this is what I am executing inside remote ssh 
ruby rubyscriptname.rb ${ref}

But this is not working. The script takes the value of the ref as ${ref} instead of it's value.

Comment: Hi, I am not sure if variables can be passed to `Execute shell script on remote host using ssh` but did you try "${ref}" and see if it works ?

Comment: Yes, I did. But it didn't work :(